# Dual problem for least squares with Tikhonov regularization

Tags: least-squares, optimization, ridge-regression

I'd like to find the dual problem for least squares with Tikhonov regularization.

For now, I have the primal problem expressed as minimize $||Ax-b||_2^2 + \gamma||x||_2^2$.

I'm introducing a dummy variable r in order to have the problem

min $||r||_2^2$ subject to $r=||Ax-b||_2^2$

Could any one provide details on expressing the lagrangian and the dual problem from there ?

Comment: Most likely you want to reformulate this as $\min \| r \|_{2}^{2}+\gamma \| x \|_{2}^{2}$ subject to $r=Ax-b$.  You can then dualize the linear equality constraints.  Your primal variables are the vectors $x$ and $r$ and the dual variables are the Lagrange multipliers $\nu$ on the equality constraints.

Comment: $L(r,x,\upsilon) = ||r||_2^2 + \gamma ||x|_2^2 + \upsilon^T(Ax -b -r)$. Taking the derivatives for each variable leads to solving three equations : (1) $2r - \upsilon = 0$, (2) $2\gamma x + A^T\upsilon = 0$ and (3) $Ax -b -r = 0$ right ? But I somehow get the solution $\upsilon = (\gamma I A^-1+A^T)^{-1} \gamma I A^{-1}2b$, which has nothing to do with the analytical solution of the primal problem, where $x = (A^TA + \gamma I) A^T b$. The duality gap should be zero, so I should get the same solution right ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Take a look at Open Journal of Statistics 2015 https://file.scirp.org/pdf/OJS_2015121116191317.pdf